# sticky nav in mobirise

Tags: nav, sticky, mobirise

I've been tinkering with Mobirise. I've laid out a quick site and wish to customize the top nav. In the current state the nav has two sections. Top and bottom. As the user scrolls the top gets hidden and the bottom gets minimized. I've altered the code slightly to keep the top in view as the user scrolls, however, it's not 100% yet and I can't seem to figure out what is causing the bottom ot overlay the top. I tried z-index setting to no avail. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

The site is here. http://arnolfodesign.com/clients/hvac/

btw, the client will want their phone number showing at all times, thus the reason for keeping the top inview.

Answer (score 1):

Find the 1365th line in the mbr additional.css
Add

```css
.cid-qv8RNySB8F .navbar-short .menu-content-top {
  height: auto;
  border: none;
}
```

instead of

```css
.cid-qv8RNySB8F .navbar-short .menu-content-top {
  height: 0;
  border: none;
}
```